# How to delete or log only top-level directory in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, scripting

Does Powershell have to always go through the sub-folders and delete those first? Can it not just delete the top-level directory which will also delete everything in it? The reason I ask is that I wrote a script to delete folders older than 120 days and output those folders to a log file.

```
   get-childitem -directory h:\agencydata\* |
  where { (get-date) - $_.lastwritetime -gt 120. } |
  remove-item -force -recurse -Verbose 4>&1 | Add-Content H:\logs\$(Get-Date -Format dd-MM-yyyy)-auto_deletes.log
```

But the log includes the hundreds of sub-directories as well. If we can't force Powershell to delete only the top-level folder, then can we force it to include only the top-level folders in the log?

Example of the log output I'm currently getting with my script:

```
Performing the operation "Remove Directory" on target "H:\agencydata\255233".
Performing the operation "Remove Directory" on target "H:\agencydata\255233\_Extracted".
Performing the operation "Remove Directory" on target "H:\agencydata\255233\_Extracted\Broker-7671-02242020080758-49".
Performing the operation "Remove Directory" on target "H:\agencydata\255233\_Extracted\Broker-7671-02242020080758-49\7671".
Performing the operation "Remove Directory" on target "H:\agencydata\255233\_Extracted\Broker-7671-02242020080758-49\7671\Accounts".
Performing the operation "Remove Directory" on target "H:\agencydata\255233\_Extracted\Broker-7671-02242020080758-49\7671\Accounts\Professional Contract Services Inc. (PCSI) - 1055312".
Performing the operation "Remove Directory" on target "H:\agencydata\255233\_Extracted\Broker-7671-02242020080758-49\7671\Accounts\Professional Contract Services Inc. (PCSI) - 1055312\2004 - 2016".
Performing the operation "Remove Directory" on target "H:\agencydata\255233\_Extracted\Broker-7671-02242020080758-49\7671\Accounts\Professional Contract Services Inc. (PCSI) - 1055312\2004 - 2016\2011".
Performing the operation "Remove Directory" on target "H:\agencydata\255233\_Extracted\Broker-7671-02242020080758-49\7671\Accounts\Professional Contract Services Inc. (PCSI) - 1055312\2004 - 2016\2011\MIP".
Performing the operation "Remove Directory" on target "H:\agencydata\255233\_Extracted\Broker-7671-02242020080758-49\7671\Accounts\Professional Contract Services Inc. (PCSI) - 1055312\2004 - 2016\2011\MIP\Quotes".
Performing the operation "Remove Directory" on target "H:\agencydata\255233\_Extracted\Broker-7671-02242020080758-49\7671\Accounts\Professional Contract Services Inc. (PCSI) - 1055312\2004 - 2016\2011\MIP\Quotes\Medical Quotes".
Performing the operation "Remove Directory" on target "H:\agencydata\255233\_Extracted\Broker-7671-02242020080758-49\7671\Accounts\Professional Contract Services Inc. (PCSI) - 1055312\2004 - 2016\2011\MIP\Quotes\Medical Quotes\Fully Insured Quotes".
Performing the operation "Remove Directory" on target "H:\agencydata\255233\_Extracted\Broker-7671-02242020080758-49\7671\Accounts\Professional Contract Services Inc. (PCSI) - 1055312\2004 - 2016\2011\MIP\Quotes\Medical Quotes\Fully Insured Quotes\2011-03-01 Trustmark medical quote".
Performing the operation "Remove Directory" on target "H:\agencydata\255233\_Extracted\Broker-7671-02242020080758-49\7671\Accounts\Professional Contract Services Inc. (PCSI) - 1055312\2004 - 2016\2011\MIP\Quotes\Medical Quotes\Fully Insured Quotes\2011-03-01 Trustmark medical quote\2011-03-01 geo access reports".
```

Example of what I would like:

```
Performing the operation "Remove Directory" on target "H:\agencydata\255233".
Performing the operation "Remove Directory" on target "H:\agencydata\25523323".
Performing the operation "Remove Directory" on target "H:\agencydata\25523343534".
Performing the operation "Remove Directory" on target "H:\agencydata\2552331".
Performing the operation "Remove Directory" on target "H:\agencydata\25523355".
Performing the operation "Remove Directory" on target "H:\agencydata\25523314".
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recurse means what it does, repeat the command fo reach objects called, otherwise, why specify it.

If you only pass the parent name, without the recurse, then it will delete the parent and all children.

When you do this without the -Recurse...

```
Remove-Item -Path C:\ParentFolder -Force -WhatIf
```

... PowerShell will warn you.

> 'The item at C:\ParentFolder has children and the Recurse parameter
> was not specified. If you continue, all children will be removed with
> the item. Are you sure you want to continue'

If you really want to see the stack of your command/code, do this:

> [Trace-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/trace-command?view=powershell-7)

```
Trace-Command -Name metadata,parameterbinding,cmdlet -Expression {Remove-Item -Path C:\ParentFolder -Force} -PSHost -Verbose
# Results
<#
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND NAMED cmd line args [Remove-Item]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [C:\ParentFolder] to parameter [Path]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         COERCE arg to [System.String[]]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Trying to convert argument value from System.String to System.String[]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             ENCODING arg into collection
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Binding collection parameter Path: argument type [String], parameter type [System.String[]], collection type Array, element type [System.String], coerceElementType
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Creating array with element type [System.String] and 1 elements
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Argument type String is not IList, treating this as scalar
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             COERCE arg to [System.String]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :                 Parameter and arg types the same, no coercion is needed.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Adding scalar element of type String to array position 0
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [System.String[]] to param [Path] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [True] to parameter [Force]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         COERCE arg to [System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Parameter and arg types the same, no coercion is needed.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [True] to param [Force] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND POSITIONAL cmd line args [Remove-Item]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND cmd line args to DYNAMIC parameters.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     DYNAMIC parameter object: [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.FileSystemProviderRemoveItemDynamicParameters]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Remove-Item]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING BeginProcessing
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING EndProcessing
#>


Trace-Command -Name metadata,parameterbinding,cmdlet -Expression {Remove-Item -Path C:\ParentFolder -Recurse -Force } -PSHost -Verbose
# Results
<#
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND NAMED cmd line args [Remove-Item]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [C:\ParentFolder] to parameter [Path]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         COERCE arg to [System.String[]]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Trying to convert argument value from System.String to System.String[]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             ENCODING arg into collection
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Binding collection parameter Path: argument type [String], parameter type [System.String[]], collection type Array, element type [System.String], coerceElementType
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Creating array with element type [System.String] and 1 elements
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Argument type String is not IList, treating this as scalar
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             COERCE arg to [System.String]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :                 Parameter and arg types the same, no coercion is needed.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Adding scalar element of type String to array position 0
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [System.String[]] to param [Path] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [True] to parameter [Recurse]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         COERCE arg to [System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Parameter and arg types the same, no coercion is needed.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [True] to param [Recurse] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :     BIND arg [True] to parameter [Force]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         COERCE arg to [System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :             Parameter and arg types the same, no coercion is needed.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 :         BIND arg [True] to param [Force] SUCCESSFUL
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND POSITIONAL cmd line args [Remove-Item]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : BIND cmd line args to DYNAMIC parameters.
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : MANDATORY PARAMETER CHECK on cmdlet [Remove-Item]
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING BeginProcessing
DEBUG: ParameterBinding Information: 0 : CALLING EndProcessing
#>
```

Lastly, PowerShell notwithstanding, you cannot remove a non-empty folder using any command on any operating system. So, recursion, even if not specified, is implied on a destructive command.

If you only want to see the parents in your log file, you have to code for that.

***Update***
As for your comment

Can you guide me to what I need to do to edit my log-output to only show those top-level folders?

... you can do something like this. Log the read result, not the remove result.

```
Get-ChildItem -directory 'C:\ParentFolder*' | 
ForEach{
    "Performing the operation on target $($PSItem.FullName)" 4>&1 | 
    Add-Content -Path "c:\logs\$(Get-Date -Format dd-MM-yyyy)-auto_deletes.log"
    $null = Remove-Item -Path $PSItem -Force
}
Get-Content -Path 'C:\logs\09-10-2020-auto_deletes.log'
# Results
<#
Performing the operation on target C:\ParentFolder
Performing the operation on target C:\ParentFolder - Copy
Performing the operation on target C:\ParentFolder - Copy - Copy
Performing the operation on target C:\ParentFolder - Copy - Copy - Copy
#>
```

Comment: What about Python or Batch?

Comment: Nope. It does not matter. This is how operating systems deal with file and folder management. Again, you cannot delete a non-empty folder tree, no matter what language you use. It's not a flaw, it's by design. So, recursion is a must. Now, how you generate your report on the effort is up to you. Yet, accepting the default output/stdout, you'll get what the OS gives you.

Comment: Okay thanks. Can you guide me to what I need to do to edit my log-output to only show those top-level folders?

Comment: Just capture the results in a variable, alter as needed, then output to a file or Only output the read to the loig file, not the Remove-Item result.  See my update for you regarding the latter.